# salesforce one app.css is not loaded?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I want to use the default salesforce one theme for our app.
how to include app.css? even I set `standardStylesheets="true"` on the `apex:page` 
app.css is not loaded for custom apex page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know that SF doesn't provide a easy way to include the SF1 CSS like coding on Froce.com. You need to write the CSS as you want. But luckily, in the Github that there is a project which maybe can help you.

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/bootstrap-sf1

If you want to write CSS by yourself, you can check this style guide:

http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/